# What is Loppa hair?

Tags: nnedi-okorafor, winds-of-harmattan

In Nnendi's story *Winds of Harmattan*, Usooko is described as having 'Loppa' hair. When I listened on LeVar Burton Reads, I couldn't tell if this was something regular I hadn't heard of, or part of the fantastic elements of the story.

I'm aware of [otjize paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otjize) used by the himba tribes (something Nnendi features in her Binti series), but that doesn't sound like what Usooka has.

What is it exactly?

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be mishearing the text. According to my copy, Asuquo is described as having "the **locked hair** of a witch". This is decribed earlier in the story:

> her hair crept down her back like ropes of black fungus. She was born
> this way, emerging from her mother’s womb with seven glistening locks
> of dada hair hanging from her head like seaweed.

"dada hair" occurs often in Okorafor's stories, and simply means dreadlocks.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that make much more sense to me now.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage If you can remember the sentence where you heard "Loppa", I can check it against the print version

Comment: I do not remember (this was ~6 months ago that I listened), but I can have a relisten tonight